# email host marked as spam mule by site with a rooster

Tags: linux, sendmail, spam, configure

Recently I was configuring sendmail on a new linux server install and there was a configuration problem. I was given a link to a website that had the image of a rooster on it and told to consult them for configuration problems.

I cant remember the url of the site, but it's apparently a well-known one.

Can someone here remind me of what the site is and how I am sposed to use it to figure out the correct configuration?

Comment: This might be a better question for http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about [the CBL](http://cbl.abuseat.org/).